# Overriding the WYSIWYG editor files in Refinery CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I am trying to override the `validator.js.erb` file. I started by running the rake task.

```
rake refinery:override javascript=wymeditor/validators
```

This created the `validators.js.erb` file in the `app/assets/wymeditor/` directory. Even though the new file is loaded at the client side, my changes are ignored as the same file is bundled by Refinery in    `wymeditor.js` file.

How do I address this issue?

Comment: You probably figured this out already but just curious did you make sure to clear both the rails and browser caches ? I know both refinery and chrome are pretty agressive about caching

Comment: For some reason Rails kept ignoring overriden validators.js.erb file and kept loading original file. As a workaround I copied validators file under another name and included it in refinery admin js. Wymeditor picked up the change and worked as expected.